# runas verb not working in windows 8?

Tags: c#, .net-framework, windows-8, runas

I am using some applications need to do some thing as an admin, so I was using the verb "runas" in windows 7 and it is working well,

However, once we migrate to windows 8, the new processes were having the same permissions as the invoker no matter what it was, so a lot of permission exceptions were thrown.

What happened to "runas" verb?
Is there a new verb or more suitable one to use?

Comment: @Timothy question is about runas verb in ShellExecute. Q belongs here on SO.

Comment: runas works fine on windows 8. Clearly your environment is a little special. So, more details are needed.

Comment: I expected as much, but that is not specified in the question.

Comment: I guess the people that migrated this here don't know about verbs and `ShellExecute`. I don't have enough rep to migrate it back where it belongs.

Comment: I have the same issue in windows 8. Setting `ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "runas"` is not working.